# DynamoDB Enhanced Client (very) slow start for 1st request, possible to do "select 1 from"?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

We are attempting to use Kotlin with AWS Lambda, and it seems that the first query executed by DynamoDbEnhancedClient always takes up to 3 seconds, while any subsequent queries takes less than  50ms.

We do have a warmup process that pre-warms these lambdas on a schedule, is there a way to fire a request via DynamoDbEnhancedClient without incurring cost? Like a describe or "select 1 from"?

Comment: There is no AWS Kotlin SDK at the moment. You mean you are using AWS SDK for Java and writing Kotlin code correct?

Comment: Correct, we are using the Java SDK